# waf will not find correct python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, waf

I've been trying to build pycairo on my machine, which ships with waf. Upon running `./waf configure`, I get the following result:

```
Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python 
Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 6, 'final', 0) 
The python version is too old, expecting (3, 1, 0)
(complete log in /Users/USER/Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0/build_directory/config.log)
```

I have python 3 installed to `/usr/local/bin/python3`, but I don't know after reading waf's documentation how to override this. I am on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about running `/usr/local/bin/python3 ./waf configure`? This should force `waf` to use the correct python version.

EDIT: Try the following --

`export PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
./waf configure`

Comment: This didn't work for me... it just reports that `/usr/local/bin` is a different path from `sys.executable`, and throws the same error.

Comment: @Muddmaker I edited my response... Could you try the new fix?